# HttpErrorResponse can not get expected response from HttpServletResponse

Tags: angular, http, interceptor

i am new on angular2,now i use a intercepter get response from server

when i return 401 error , my java server code like this:

```
// httpServletResponse's type is HttpServletResponse    
httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
httpServletResponse.getWriter().write("required login");
```

and my interceptor on angular2 code like this:

```
 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
this.rest = this.inj.get(RestProvider);
return next.handle(req).catch(err =>{
  console.log(err);
});
```

then the err is so confused:
[HttpErrorResponse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S73yn.png)

the status is always 0 and it didn't receive the error message from server,however,the network on developer tools of chrome can receive the response:
[headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DkcM.png)

(i am sorry that i don't have permission to upload a piture, just two links)
i have searched many questions about this, but can not solved my question either. can anyone help me？ thx very much!

Comment: what behavior do you expect?

Comment: the status is 401 when session is Expired, and is 404 when page is not found , so on.  but the status is always 0 and it didn't receive the error message, just show "unknown error".  i am sorry for my poor  English, i hope you can understand.

Comment: what do you see in the network tab?

Comment: the "headers" show : https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DkcM.png

Comment: what's on the response tab?

Comment: response is empty

Comment: then, when i remove the interceptor and just catch the error from subscribe,it return the same confused error as from interceptor

Comment: I guess you'll need to debug it. Find `HttpResponseBase` and see what values it's being initialized with

Comment: okay, i wil debug it, and then reply , thx~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am sorry to reply so late. it seems that angular2 can not analysis HttpServletResponse, i solve it by a other way:

if a 401 error, i will redirect to 'unauthorized' by forward

```
 httpServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher("unauthorized").forward(httpServletRequest,httpServletResponse);
```

then in my 'unauthorized':

```
 @GET
@Path("unauthorized")
public Response unAuthorized(){
    return RestResult.failure(401,"need login",401);
}
```

RestRsult is a class package some response:

```
public static Response failure(int errorcode, String errormsg,int status) {
    ResponseFailureObj result = new ResponseFailureObj(errorcode, errormsg);
    return Response.status(status).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity(result).build();
}
```

then, i will receive status 401 on angular2 HttpErrorResponse and receive error message instead of unknown error or empty message.